# Migration from magento 1.9.2.4 to magento 2.1.2 unable to get product view page

Tags: magento2, magento2-migration-tool

I would like to migrate the **magento 1.9.2.4** to **magento 2.1.2** i got the attributes and products and categories etc.. but i am unable to view product page (**showing blank page**) in the front end page, as well as from the admin side also i am facing the same issue as shown in the below screenshot. could you please help me how to fix this.

[image]

I am getting an error like exception file lo error msg:

```
> [2017-01-17 06:47:42] main.CRITICAL: exception
> 'Magento\Framework\Exception\FileSystemException' with message 'Cannot
> read contents from file
> "/var/www/magentojt/pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_‌​AU/mage/requirejs/mi‌​xins.js"
> Warning!file_get_contents(/var/www/magentojt/pub/static/admi‌​nhtml/Magento/backen‌​d/en_AU/mage/require‌​js/mixins.js):
> failed to open stream: No such file or directory' in
> /var/www/magentojt/vendor/magento/framework/Filesystem/Drive‌​r/File.php:149
```

Comment: Please check the `var\log`

Comment: Thanks for reply  i am getting an error like exception file lo error msg:
[2017-01-17 06:47:42] main.CRITICAL: exception 
'Magento\Framework\Exception\FileSystemException' with message 
'Cannot read contents from file "/var/www/magentojt/pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_AU/mage/requirejs/mixins.js"
Warning!file_get_contents(/var/www/magentojt/pub/static/adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_AU/mage/requirejs/mixins.js): failed to open stream: No such file or directory' 
in /var/www/magentojt/vendor/magento/framework/Filesystem/Driver/File.php:149

Comment: Please run `chmod -R 777 var` or `chmod -R 777 var/generation var/cache var/di pub/static`

Answer (score 0):

- Delete the "`di`" folder located in var directory
- Run this command in project root folder `command:cd
  /yourmagentoroot/bin`
- Then run this command sudo `./magento setup:di:compile`
- Finally give file/directory permissions.

**Source :** http://blog.trimantra.com/error-magento-2-upgrade-command/